Static file references differ on servers with same configuration
I'm using Django 5.1.3 for a project and the template references to the static files, despite being identical on three different servers, don't all point to the same relative location.
The template tag {% static 'mystyle.css' %} is rendered in the following ways on our different servers (right-click, view source, HTML, yada yada):

Server 1 (DEV): rendered/served HTML references /djangodir/static/mystyle.css
Server 2 (TEST): rendered/served HTML references /djangodir/static/mystyle.css
Server 3 (PROD): rendered/served HTML references /djangodir/djangodir/static/mystlye.css

The first two work. What would cause a template to render two different paths with the same tag? settings.py is the same on all the servers (all the files in /djangodir and /staticfilesdir are identical). ./manage.py collectstatic has been run on all servers. Apache's httpd.conf is identical across them. Why does PROD get the extra djangodir rendered in the path from staticfiles? How would I go about further debugging this particular issue?
